# SQLite - Updating multiple tables

Tags: android, sqlite, android-studio, android-sqlite

Can anyone help me fixing the problem in my query?

I'm trying to call a function to update multiple tables which have a value of `"1"` in column `"col"`, but it's not working,

**my_function**

```
public long updateNow() {
        mDbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(mContext);
        mDb = mDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();

        int doneClear = 0;
        String base_value = "1"; // update all column "col" where value of 1

        ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
        initialValues.put("col", "0"); // Update all column "col" with 0

        doneClear = mDb.update(SQLITE_TABLE_ONE, initialValues, "col=" + base_value, null);
        doneClear = mDb.update(SQLITE_TABLE_TWO, initialValues, "col=" + base_value, null);
        doneClear = mDb.update(SQLITE_TABLE_THREE, initialValues, "col=" + base_value, null);
        doneClear = mDb.update(SQLITE_TABLE_FOUR, initialValues, "col=" + base_value, null);
        doneClear = mDb.update(SQLITE_TABLE_FIVE, initialValues, "col=" + base_value, null);
        doneClear = mDb.update(SQLITE_TABLE_SIX, initialValues, "col=" + base_value, null);
        Log.w(TAG, Integer.toString(doneClear));
        return doneClear;
    }
```

This code is not working, i'm can't get why.
Nothing happens in column `col`.

Anyway, that code is based on my previous query, which is working fine.

**working_update_query**

```
public long updates(String recent_value, String _id, String table_name) {
        ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
        initialValues.put("recent_value", recent_value);
        Log.w(TAG, String.valueOf(initialValues) + " WITH ID OF " + _id + " IN TABLE OF " + table_name);
        return mDb.update(table_name, initialValues, "_id=" + _id, null);
    }
```

I'm stuck here for almost 1 hour, can't figure out the problem.
Can anyone help me please?

Comment: seriously ... you should stare on `"_id="  + _id` until you get it ... **next time define** *it's not working*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this using wildcards to appropriately inject the update parameters, like this:

```
int updateCount = db.update(
   TABLE_NAME,
   newValues,
   "col = ?",
   new String[] {String.valueOf(colValue)}
);
```

For a quick sample check out [this tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidSQLite/article.html#sqliteoverview_rawquery).